# adding javascript loops with money currency

Tags: javascript, while-loop

Hello can some one help me...

we made a currency in our class and where trying to make a loop that adds the two numbers to see how much "keith bucks" we have .. thats the name of the currency " keith bucks"
here the info we have

var Keith = 18;

var austin = 4.5;

var marc = 2;

var kaleb = 1.29;

var hayley = 0.9;

var michaela = 0.45;

var zacc = 0.0225;

Comment: Have you tried attempting yourself? So share your workings, inorder you help you.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking here but it made me laugh!!

Comment: Basically you want the sum of these numbers? Please provide some code and better explanation.

Comment: If you want to _loop_ over something, then start with an array or object that holds the data, not individual variables.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing to loop over here.  You've defined each person as a separate variable.

Consider changing your data structure:

```
let people = [
  { name: 'Keith', amount: 18 },
  { name: 'austin', amount: 4.5 },
  // etc. etc.
];
```

From there you can use something like this:

```
let total = 0;
people.forEach((person) => {
  total += person.amount;
});
console.log(total);
```

Once you have that mastered, look into [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Also, be very careful with currency.  Don't get bit by floating point rounding.  [How can I format numbers as money in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript)

Comment: Don't you want him to try?

Comment: @Smit Of course I do.  What's there to try with the code in the question?  This person has no idea what they're doing.  A little help at the beginning can get them moving.  You should also note that I included some links for further reading.

Comment: As @Brad mentions please be very careful with floating point rounding. You may wish to round the `person.amount` before running the calculation or at least rounding it at the end.